# Converting a huge file with a JSON document per line into a single JSON list

Tags: python, json

As you can see below I have a string and I want to convert it into standard JSON.

```
{"domain":"345","path":"/"}
{"domain":"5432","path":"/"}
{"domain":"345","path":"/"}
{"domain":"345","path":"/"}
{"domain":"23456","path":"/"}
{"domain":"2345","path":"/"}
{"domain":"3456","path":"/"}
{"domain":"123","path":"/"}
```

I have a file of 12GB which contains data exactly like this.

I want to create a new file where data is like this -

```
[
   {"domain":"345","path":"/"},
   {"domain":"5432","path":"/"},
   {"domain":"345","path":"/"},
   {"domain":"345","path":"/"},
   {"domain":"23456","path":"/"},
   {"domain":"2345","path":"/"},
   {"domain":"3456","path":"/"},
   {"domain":"123","path":"/"}
]
```

Comment: Do you really need to use Python for this? It strikes me as overkill.

Comment: Are all the objects on a single line?

Comment: unmatched quotes - it was a mistake

Comment: (re: "Python strikes me as overkill" -- this could be very efficiently implemented using a one-liner in `jq`, granted, needing to use `--stream` mode to avoid needing to store the document in memory)

Comment: BTW, JSONL (the format of your input file) is a legit thing, and a lot of tools/libraries/etc can parse it directly. If you control the program that needs to read the input file, it might be worth seeing about enabling it to load JSONL directly instead of requiring a conversion to JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those rare special cases where it's safe to treat JSON as raw text.

```
with open('out.json', 'w') as outfile, open('in.jsonl', 'r') as infile:
  outfile.write('[\n')
  for line in infile:
    outfile.write(f'  {line.rstrip()},\n')
  outfile.write(']\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Charles Duffy's answer, you may treat JSON as simple text; and here's a reasonable one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print"["}{print "  "$0","}END{print"]"}' infile.json > outfile.json
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a Unix command

```
$ cat Clients.txt
Slide clipboard items to delete them
$ sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/' Clients.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't add the leading `[` and tailing `]` -- and the OP tagged this as a Python question.

Comment: Also, `sed -z` on a file with no literal NULs means you're loading the whole file into the pattern buffer (which is to say, into memory) at once. That is severely Not Okay for a 12gb input file.